# Компиляция C++, используя PHP - ограничить

Tags: cmd, php, c++

Итак, передо мной стоит такая задача:(звездочкой буду помечать то, что сделано)

- *Получить cpp файл
- *Скомпилировать его
- Дать ему **минимальные права**, чтобы он ничего плохого не сделал
- **Ограничить время** его выполнения (В случае превышения лимита-остановить)
- **Ограничить память** (В случае превышения лимита-остановить)

Как воплотить в реальность последние три пункта? Я слышал, что подобное можно сделать через Delphi, если кто-то знает-то как? Я, безусловно, ничего не могу требовать, но лучше бы средствами PHP и cmd это бы сделать.

Вот код, который на данный момент просто компилирует файл:(вдруг будет нужен)

```
<?php
exec('C:\MinGWStudio\MinGW\bin\g++.exe Z:\путь\к\cpp\test.cpp 2>&1', $output);
?>
<pre>
<?print_r($output);?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Создайте пользователя с минимальными правами (например, разрешите ему чтение и запись только в одном каталоге, запретите запуск тех системных утилит, которые могут навредить машине) и запускайте программу от его имени. Как я вижу, ваш сервер работает под Windows, так что осуществить запуск программы от имени другого пользователя можно консольной командой `runas`. Насчёт ограничения времени и памяти: пока процесс выполнения программы не завершился, каждые несколько секунд вызываем `tasklist` для определения, запущен ли процесс, и если да, то сколько памяти он потребляет. Если больше, чем нужно - убиваем его командой `taskkill`. Само собой, запуск программы в этом случае должен происходить в фоновом режиме, иначе скрипт будет выполняться пока программа не завершится или пока не истечёт лимит времени на выполнения PHP-скрипта (устанавливается в htaccess). Учтите, если ваш проект когда-либо будет работать на Linux хостинге, эту часть придётся переписать с использованием команд Linux.

Comment: спасибо огромное! но как ограничить время и память?

Comment: Обновил ответ